# common javascript api between iOS & Droid / nativescript core

Tags: nativescript, language-interoperability

Just looking into Nativescript; the "core" bit of it seems really interesting in that you can call native APIs directly from JS, but it seems it is a completely different API for iOS and Droid (e.g. matching the respective native APIs on each platform).  See attached screen shot.  Does anyone know if someone has made a common JS API between iOS and Droid for nativescript core?  At least a subset of calls?  Otherwise you still have 2 APIs to deal with (doubling the code base), but at least it is one language.

[ios vs. android api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZbo5.png)

Comment: NativeScript is the common API layer, if it is not common, then you can go into core and use it anyway.

Comment: In my apps, I'd say at least 95% of the code is common, maybe more like 98%.